# Managing records in db for multi language via CMS

Tags: mysql, localization

Dont know if this is the right place to ask this question, but I have a site that allows someone to add stories. I need to support multi-language so in the mysql database the story table is setup this way:

```
en_title
sp_title
en_story
sp_story
```

Yes I know, but I cant change the database schema so this is what I have to work with. So with the database setup like this, how would could I allow someone to manage their story in both english and spanish version? I have a dashboard where they can login and add/edit any story they created, but Im having a hard time wrapping my head around a solution that would allow them to manage the same story in different languages. Do I show a list of stories in all languages they filled it out in? Then when they click to edit a story it only shows that language version? For example they log into their dashboard, they have one story thats in english and spanish, do I show them a list:

```
Story 1 English Version
Story 1 Spanish Version
```

Then if they click either or it will show a form with that story in the version they selected, english or spanish? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could show a list like the one above where the user have the options of editing and viewing the stories. If he chooses to edit, the page opens a form right under the item where he can make the changes he want and re-submit it.

[image: ddasda Stories List]

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this? You list the titles once with the title in the default language and provide a list of languages. Clicking on the title would open the default language and if you click on one of the other language names it will open the post in that language. The plus sign next to language name indicates that the post does not exist at the moment and that clicking it will create a node for that language.

[image: Multilingual Listing]

Disclaimer: I work for a localization company and this is the UI that we use for our WordPress plugin

Comment: Though I accepted the first answer your post was also very helpful. Thank you for your post!